# htaccess with cakephp on linux host cpanel 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I am having an issue with the `.htaccess` file i think. I recieve constant internal 500 errors. I have tried many different solutions around the web. Here is what my `.htaccess` files look like:

**ROOT ACCESS**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**app/ HTACCESS**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**app/webroot/ HTACCESS**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Notice:** my project is in root directory - public_html/

Comment: Two app/ directories?

Comment: no just one app @slbteam08

Comment: Why do you have two *.htaccess* files in you app directory according to your question?

Comment: check rewrite module of your server